# Is there any way to add a 3.0 usb to a Packard Bell EasynoteTJ75? Motherboard shown

Tags: motherboard, usb-3

Is there any way to add a 3.0 usb to a Packard Bell EasynoteTJ75? Motherboard shown

I need to take big backups of this laptop's files to an external hard drive regularly.

[image]

[image]

For example those two lonely usb ports on the right, or it doesn't make a difference and the problem is the whole motherboard?

Comment: Just a note for you when you add your pictures to your question. When you add the link please add the direct links to the pictures instead of the one for the page that contains the pictures. That way when someone comes to embed them to your question, they don't have to visit a webpage first. No harm done but just for next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can't.

The easy way would be an expresscard slot used with a expresscard/usb 3.0 adaptor, and I don't see one

There's a one *really* terrible option
 - mini PCI-e/USB 3.0 cards exist, but they typically have a great big header you need to connect to a suitable USB 3.0 port + female header. You'd essentially trade off wifi for USB 3.0, and you'd need to find something that would fit inside your existing wireless card slot, and break out the sockets somehow. Not seen anything that would fit in a laptop. .

Comment: Thanks to your answer I begin to understand...
I read around that this laptop has this mini PCI-e thing (the reason I was hopeful when I wrote the question)
So the "only" problem is that it is being used by the wifi and its position?
My atheros ar5b93 has the same connector of a mini PCI-e/USB 3.0 card right?
I would have to find a PCI-e/USB 3.0 card that fits somehow?
This is really interesting.

Comment: and space. Most cards I saw when googling have a large protruding socket on top to plug in a header connector.

Comment: Really grateful to you Journeyman Geek...
Only one last question, only to get the idea, something that looks like this?
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1jMIpJXXXXXbzXFXXq6xXFXXXY/New-10pcs-lot-font-b-Mini-b-font-font-b-pcie-b-font-to-font-b.jpg
I would have to keep the bottom lid of the laptop open (the usb cable underneath wouldn't be a problem because I already keep my laptop back raised to help cpu/fan).

Comment: That's pretty much the best you could do. Its terrible though. ;p

Answer (score 2):

You can't just "add" an USB3.0 port onto an existing motherboard that isn't designed for one. (As Eric F also just said.)
And that EasyNote of yours doesn't have any internal support for fast interfaces.

There is also no PCMCIAA or PCIe/ExpressCard card-slot and the card-reader on the side is also limited to USB2.0.
The LAN port is also limited to 100 Mb/s as far as I can tell.

That means that the fastest way to copy large amounts of data to/from the laptop is still going to be a USB 2.0 stick or external harddrive or the card-reader. That should give you in theory about 480 Mb/s, but in practice it will be around 300 Mb/s.

If the LAN port can do Gigabit (not very likely) than copying over Gigabit LAN to either a NAS or a USB3.0 disk shared by another computer would be about 2 to 2.5 times as fast.

Comment: This hurted so much. I didn't worry about such things in 2009. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Eh, 'modern' cardbus slots are expresscard I believe.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You are right.. I actually meant that when I wrote PCIe (ExpressCard is a simplified and hotpluggable PCIe interface.) Have added that in the answer.

Comment: @user682501 its a lower end, consumer centred system - stuff like that was par for the course. Even my base model 2011 thinkpad x220 didn't have USB 3 (while the core i7 model did) - with USB 3 becoming common only in 2012. Its a perfectly good machine considering its age. Backing up over network and using incrementals is the smart way to do this

Comment: About the LAN, Device Manager shows my nic as "Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet" so shouldn't it have gigabit port? Confused.

Comment: @user682501 I had no idea which exact NIC would be in there, but I guessed it would be 100 mb/s as those where most common. (Packard made this laptop in several variants, with different NIC's.) The Broadcom you have is indeed Gigabit.